# How can I use web services for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, web-services

How can i use web services and also connect to the server in iphone?

Comment: This is one of the most commonly asked questions around here, and is a duplicate of the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018369/accessing-web-service-from-iphone , among others.

Answer (score 0):

I can only offer some references here you might have probably Googled them yourself:

[Toolkit for Web Service-Backed iPhone Apps](http://blog.costan.us/2009/04/toolkit-for-iphone-web-service.html)
[iPhone Programming Tutorial – Intro to SOAP Web Services](http://icodeblog.com/2008/11/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-intro-to-soap-web-services/)
[Creating an iPhone-based Web Service](http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/09/creating-an-iphone-based-web-s.html)
[Googled Results](http://www.google.com/search?q=iphone+web+service+call)

Answer (score 0):

I have heard good things about using JSON especially [TouchJSON](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchJSON).

Also, here is a [tutorial](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/) from MobileOrchard that uses JSON (but not TouchJSON).